# How to bind data from xml tag to combo box in xamdatagrid or datagrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, xamdatagrid

### xml file.

```
<Products>
   <ProductTemplate>
       <ProductID> 1</ProductID>
       <ProductLot>11</ProductLot>
       <Product>product1</product>
       <Product>product1</product>
<ProductTemplate>
<Products>
 .....
  ....
```

I'm able to get "productID" and "productLot" in xamdatagrid. Now I've to add "Product" into xamdatagrid as a comboBox. Below is the code in  xaml file.

```
                    <igDP:UnboundField Name="Product" Label="Product Name">
                        <igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                            <igDP:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}" AllowEdit="True">
                                <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
                                        <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="Combo_Loaded"/>
                                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}" />

                                    </Style>
                                </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                            </igDP:FieldSettings>
                        </igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                    </igDP:UnboundField>
                </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
            </igDP:FieldLayout>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Now the challenge is "Product" values are not populating in combo box.

below is the display() function viewmodel class

```
public void display(XamDataGrid dataGridView1)
        {


            XmlReader xmlFile;
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("C:/Wafers/WaferGen.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
            dataGridView1.DataContext = ds.Tables[0]; 
}
```

I would like to know how to retrieve the values in "product" from xml file and then how to bind to the combo box inside the xamdatagrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is not formatted properly. Below will help you get the list of products out of the XML and then you can bind it to the control you want, in your case `combobox`

```
string productXML = @"<Products>
                        <ProductTemplate>
                          <ProductID> 1</ProductID>
                          <ProductLot>11</ProductLot>
                          <Product>product1</Product>
                          <Product>product1</Product>
                        </ProductTemplate>
                     </Products>";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(productXML);
//This will give you the list of Products which you can bind with your control
var listOfProducts = xdoc.Descendants("Products").Elements("ProductTemplate").Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "Product").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and your time Richa Garg. Solution not working in my code. I'm taking the input from "product.xml" file. So I tried with XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:/Products/Product.xml") - it's not working. I have also tried with your code snippet . No luck. Data is not populating in combobox in xamdatagrid. I'm not sure whether my binding statement is correct or not.

Comment: Can you try with binding a combobox out of datagrid, just to check if there is some problem in binding. As my code is running at my machine

Comment: Combobox is populating in xamdatagrid, but the list is empty. Unable to figure it out..

Comment: Richa Garg , your solution is working fine now. I was able to figure it out in my code. Thanks for your valuable time and help.